# Kalman Filter without transition dynamics

Tags: probability-theory, matrix-equations, kalman-filter

Suppose I have 1-dimensional process with no dynamics:

$x_{n+1} = x_{n}$,

e.g. a gyroscope which measures angular velocity.

Angular velocity measured by a gyroscope for the step $ n $:

(1) $ x^{m}_{n} = x^{t}_{n} + x^{b}_{n} + x^{w}_{n} $

(2) $ x^{b}_{n} = x^{b}_{n-1} + x^{w}_{n} $

where

$x^{w}_n = \sigma_{gn}*w_{n}, \{ \sigma_{gn} = \sigma_{n}*\frac{1}{\sqrt{dt}}, w_{n} = N(0,1) \}$

$x^{b}_{n} = \sigma_{gb}*w_n, \{ \sigma_{gb} = \sigma_{b}*\sqrt{dt}, w_{n} = N(0,1) \} $

In other words, gyroscope's measured value is a sum of:

1. True angular velocity - $x^{t}_{n}$.
2. Bias (or "random walk") - $x^{b}_{n}$.
3. White noise - $x^{w}_{n}$.

Bias is an "integral" or a "sum" of white noise, and values $ \sigma_{n}, \sigma_{b} $ are determined from a datasheet or an experiment setup.

In addition to the gyroscope, which measures angular velocity with high rate, I have visual odometry sensor which measures angular velocity with relatively low rate:

$ y_{n} = x^{t}_{n} + v^{w}_{n}$, where $ v^{w}_{n}$ is a visual odometry measurement noise.

My final goal is to estimate $ X = \begin{bmatrix}
x^{t}_{n} \\ x^{b}_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$, or equivalently $ X = \begin{bmatrix}
(x^{m}_{n} - x^{b}_{n}) \\ x^{b}_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$

In order to do it, I construct Kalman filter equations:

STEP 1. Build a model.

I don't have dynamics equation for the angular velocity. I have only bias dynamics.

So equation becomes:

$X_{n} = X_{n-1} + Q_{n-1} $, or equivalently:

$\begin{bmatrix} x^{t}_{n} \\ x^{b}_{n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin {bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
(x^{m}_{n-1} - x^{b}_{n-1}) \\ x^{b}_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} x^{w}_{n-1}$

And here I stuck. This matrix equation is not consistent with (1) and (2) because I can't propagate previous state to the current state.

Does it mean I can't use Kalman filter here?

Comment: I think I need somewhat like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4045316/655170) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4043900/655170) clarification.

Comment: Are you sure that the zero mean Gaussian white noise that drives the random walk of the bias also acts as the zero mean Gaussian white noise of the gyroscope measurement?

Comment: I use [this](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr/wiki/IMU-Noise-Model) model.

Comment: In case your browser failes to display the "bias" part, please refer to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20201012233954/https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr/wiki/IMU-Noise-Model)

Comment: And [here](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-SITL_gazebo/blob/master/src/gazebo_imu_plugin.cpp#L189) is an implementation example. In addition to the first link I provided it also contains some "process" transition for the bias, and actually I cannot explain why. But the principle is the same. First we integrate the bias, then add white noise to the integrated bias.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen do you have any ideas?